# draw and method visit in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, draw

I'm newbie in cocos2d.
I create a class draw a TextButton:

```
TextButton *textButton1, *textButton2;
```

but I don't use method:

```
[self addChild: textButton1];
[self addChild: textButton2];
```

I try draw in:

```
-(void)visit{
[super visit];
[textButton1 visit];
[textButton2 visit];
}
```

and method visit of TextButton is:

```
CCLabelTTF *text;
-(void)visit{
[super visit];
[text visit];
}
```

but the program draw only textButton2.
Can you explain for me, and how is method visit and draw work?

Comment: You really need to add both as child even if you want to do custom drawing. The issue is possibly that for some reason drawing a non-child node actually works in this circumstance. If you want to custom-draw each button separately, you'll need two subclasses of TextButton, each with its own visit/draw method.

Comment: Can your explain more? I customed method visit.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not drawing textButton2 above textButton1? Try to comment the [textButton2 visit]; line and check what happens.